# Difficulty with numpy.append(). It works when I type it myself into IDLE but not when run

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I appreciate this isn't a very general or applicable problem for anyone else  but it has me stumped and might teach me more than I think.

```
    def gradient_descent((x,y)):
        x = (x,y)[0]
        y = (x,y)[1]
        point_history_x[0] = x
        point_history_y[0] = y #set initial states
        while numpy.linalg.norm(f_prime((x,y))) >= 0.1: #modulus of gradient
            x = x - gamma*f_prime((x,y))[0]
            y = y - gamma*f_prime((x,y))[1] #find next point
            numpy.append(point_history_x,x)
            numpy.append(point_history_y,y) #add to history of point movement
        return point_history_x, point_history_y
```

Earlier, point_history_x (and y) are defined globally as numpy.zeros((1)).
When run for point (0,0), it returns 0 for both history arrays. When I type each level out myself into a python shell, it works fine and creates an array of the variations x; but when I run the module, it just returns the input.

All evidence seems to point to me using append incorrectly, but like I've said, I type it just the same in a shell and it runs fine.

It's really fustrating, any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2 suggestions: give us an example with just the append, without the f_prime stuff.  And demonstrate how you are calling the function.  As the answer suggests, how you use this function may be more important than its internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append in this case returns a new array. It does not alter `point_history_x`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2.0])
>>> np.append(a, 1)
array([ 2.,  1.])
>>> a
array([ 2.])
>>> a = np.append(a, 1)
>>> a
array([ 2.,  1.])
>>>
```

What we see is that `np.append` works - no exceptions or anything - but `a` is not modified by the call, it just returns a new array. The second time I call `np.append` I save the result by assigning it to `a`.

There is also some unconventional/redundant stuff going on in other parts of your code. Tuple parameter unpacking is not ideal as it has been [removed in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) (thought 2to3 will convert automatically for you) but the main reason is it's just making things more complicated here. You could change

```
def gradient_descent((x,y)):
    x = (x,y)[0]
    y = (x,y)[1]
```

to either

```
def gradient_descent(pt):
    x, y = pt
```

or

```
def gradient_descent(x,y):
```

and call the code with `gradient_descent(*pt)`.

I also think you'll be better off using a normal Python list for `point_history_x` and `point_history_y`. With a NumPy array you'll end up allocating large amounts of memory in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Just to be explicit: this looks like it "works" after the first line, when `np.append(a, 1)` shows an array with `1` at the end, but the interpreter is just printing the output, and as @MrE shows, the output must be saved.